# Cannot load such file uglifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I keep getting this error:

```
throw Error("LoadError:cannot load such file -- uglifier\n  (in /var/www/dev/app)
```

I can't handle this error on Rails 4.1.4.
This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'unicorn'
```

I tried to keep the app as light as possible so I removed turbolinks, and all those initial gems:

```
 -gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
 -gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
 -gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'  
 -gem 'turbolinks'
```

I used `rake assets:precompile` or `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` and I keep getting that the JS file wrong compiled.

This is my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

And this is my production.rb:

```
# Compress JavaScripts and CSS. 
# config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
# config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

# Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out (or remove) this line from "config/production.rb" (and other environment config files):

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

Otherwise, it will try to use uglifier during the build process.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but in case some people are having this same issue, I decided to answer.

---

Try removing the uglifier gem from your Gemfile entirely and don't forget to 'bundle install'.